# How to run a JS function residing in a VF page once a Queueable class executed from the controller class finishes its execution?

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, queueable-apex, queueable-interface

I have a command button in my VF page (ABC.page)  -

```
<apex:commandLink id="DownloadDOC"  onclick="getAllDataForDoc('{!listOfObjects}')" title="Download Document" reRender="none" styleClass="downloadButton" >
       <span class="add-stmt-btn icon-size fa-download"></span>
</apex:commandLink>
```

The command button calls the JavaScript function -

```
function getAllDataForDoc(listOfObjects) {
        getData();        
}
```

The JS function calls the getData() actionFunction which is also defined within the VF page. Also it needs to call another JavaScript function generateDocument() once getData() is executed completely -

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!getAllData}" name="getData"  status="loadingMessage" oncomplete="generateDocument('{!entireJson}', '{!listOfObjects}', '{!docName}');">
</apex:actionFunction>
```

This eventually calls getAllData() method written within the controller of the VF page (ABCController.cls)

```
public void getAllData() {
       DocCreatorQueueable dcq = new DocCreatorQueueable();
       ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(dcq);
}
```

The getAllData() method eventually calls a class which implements Queueable interface as it needs to do large amount of processing which is causing APEX CPU Limit to exceed when run in synchronous context.

I have 2 questions here -

1. How do I check the status of whether the queueable class has
   finished execution or not ? If the execution is finished then I want
   to run the JavaScript function generateDocument() which calls a JS
   library in order to generate a document.
2. The generateDocument()
   function call needs certain parameters in order for it generate the
   document. The values of these variables is calculated when the
   queuable class finishes execution. How do I store these values and
   pass them to the JS function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to say that if CPU time is your issue, you're probably better off returning the data to the client as soon as possible and implementing the processing in JavaScript. Apex works *fine* as a programming language and database tasks, but JavaScript absolutely beats Apex in raw speed.

```java
// Apex
DateTime t1 = DateTime.now();
for(Integer i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
}
DateTime t2 = DateTime.now();
Assert.fail(''+(t2.getTime()-t1.getTime())); // 10,000+ ms
```

```js
// JavaScript
let t1 = new Date();
for(let i = 0; i < 5e5; i++) {
}
let t2 = new Date();
console.log(t2 - t1); // 11 ms
```

As you can see, JavaScript is 1,000 times faster for an empty loop. Whatever you can do in Apex, you can do in JavaScript much faster<sup>†</sup>.

To that end, my philosophy is that one should do as little on the server as possible, and no more.

I get that I'm suggesting rewriting the entire whatever-it-is-you-are-doing, but that really would be the best option.

You could do it all with just `apex:remoteObjects` and some client-side code, or at worst, a `@RemoteAction` function to get the data from Apex, no processing, and do the rest client-side.

Of course, if you absolutely **must** use Apex, then you'll need two pieces.

First, to check if the process is done, you can use a simple `apex:actionPoller` that calls an Apex method every five seconds to query the `AsyncApexJob` object to check the status.

Next, to get the results, you need to persist that data into a record so it can be queried. I'd probably `JSON.serialize` the data result and store it in a `ContentDocument`, setting the Title of the file to the Job ID of the Queueable call. This way you can query it after confirming the status is completed. On failure, you can set up a `TransactionFinalizer` to store some data regarding the failure condition, which you can also pick up using this polling loop.

---

<sup>†</sup> *This difference will vary on the debug levels set up in Apex and the power of your computing device, but you should expect orders of magnitude better performance with JavaScript*.

Comment: Okay for now I would need to go with processing using the AsyncApexJob itself. I am seeing one more problem, i.e., whenver I initialize  "private Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();", the apex job is failing with error "Failed: First error: [INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY] Access to entity 'pck__Log__Feed' denied. I don't see any object with such name in my org and also I have provided all the permissions to the user. What could be the reason for this error ?

Comment: @KnightoftheVale The error is on a Chatter Feed setting for the `pck__Log` object. This would be a package you've installed in your org with the namespace `pck`, though I'm not sure what that is. Are you sure you've enabled Chatter for that user? I think we're going to need a new question for this, because we'd have to see more of your code to properly assist you.

Comment: I switched to a new dev org and the chatter related error disappeared. Your solution worked. Thanks a lot for the help ! :)

Comment: If at all in future we need to complete the entire processing using javascript code itself., would there be any governor limits that would apply to the javascript running inside the visualforce page ? Could it be possible that a long running javascript operation inside the page cause a 'Apex CPU Time Limit Exceeded' error, or so ?

Comment: @KnightoftheVale It'd be a "this page has stopped responding" type error, but you'd need a lot of data before you had that kind of problem.

Comment: As part of the proecssing we are converting some object api names to object labels using Schema.getGlobalDescribe() in the apex backend. Would this be possible in javascript ?

Comment: @KnightoftheVale [`$ObjectType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_objecttype.htm) can be used to get any describe metadata you want. You can also use RemoteAction and other APIs to get that information through Apex if you want.

Comment: I have a follow up question to this problem. Please take a look - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399978/how-to-prevent-the-parent-queueable-job-from-having-a-complete-status-until-th