# How to prevent the parent Queueable Job from having a 'Complete' status until the chained child Queueable job completes?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, queueable-apex

This is more of a theoretical question.

- I have an action button on a VisualForce page which downloads a PDF with large data.
- When the action button is clicked, it invokes a Queueable job through the VisualForce page controller which does some processing and saves the resulting JSON in a Content Document with title as Id of the Queueable job.
- On the VisualForce page I have an apex:ActionPoller which runs and keeps polling the status of the Queueable job.

  - As soon as the status of the job changes to 'Completed', the controller queries the Content Document where the 'Title' is equal to the Id of the Queueable job, and then finally sends the JSON data to the VisualForce page.

    - The VisualForce page finally passes this JSON to a JavaScript library which converts it to a PDF and downloads it.

So this approach was working fine until the amount of data to process increased and the system started throwing an Apex CPU time limit exceeded exception.

What I am trying to do to overcome this issue is to divide the data to process across multiple chained Queueable jobs wherein once the user clicks on the Download button on the UI, the first Queueable job only processes a certain amount of data and stores the JSON into a content document where Title of is equal to the Id of the job.

- The Id of this Queueable job along with reamining part of data to process is passed to another chained Queueable job.
- Once this other job completes execution, it will query the same Content Document created by the first Queueable job using the Id passed to it, and then update the same JSON with the remaining data.

The question I have is that I want the apex:ActionPoller to only pick up the final JSON once the final child Queueable job completes processing. That only seems possible if I can keep the status of the initial parent Queueable job in waiting until the child Queueable job completes.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: How is large data coming in Salesforce? Is it via API or something else ?

Comment: I suggest you reply on data in the record to indicate when the processing finally completes, rather than relying on the ID of a job. It is not possible to control the status of your queueable based on chained queueables.